# Android - any alternative for android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I develop Android apps. I use Eclipse IDE, Android SDK API 16. I need an alternative to Android emulator, except BlueStacks and YouWave.

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with the emulator?  I've found that if I leave it open in between builds, you can skip the overhead of having to restart the emulator each time you want to test.

Comment: Yes i know, but it can't give me workaround !
I am only get error...

Comment: as said in previous commentt, do not close the emulator. and if you use intel image instead of arm, and install the intel haxm (in sdk extras) it will be super fast for phone emulator and tablet will be fast enough.

Comment: @tkcsam Even now after 9 months from your comment, the default emulator is so slow it can't be used for OpenGL ES testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Emu is very slow i use my phone. If you set it usb debgging on in your setting and then hook it up via usb I Really like it that way.

Answer (score 4):

There are currently two best options for replacing the emulator and one option to improve it:

1) Now Geymotion already has Android 2.3 imagem which makes Bluestacks rather obsolete.

> BlueStacks for Android 2.3, but for some reason you said you don't want this one. Anyway it is very useful, because no other emulator is both fast and able to emulate Android 2.3 with OpenGL ES 2.0. [You can still root it](http://www.xda-developers.com/android/how-to-install-and-root-the-latest-bluestacks/) if you don't like their launcher.

2) [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) is probably the best there is for Android 4.x. They are planning to release 2.3 image soon. It works as a special virtual machine in VirtualBox running Android OS. It's very fast, integrates to Eclipse - I haven't tried that, adb is good enough for me. It runs smoother than Bluestacks and has many options to configure. Android 4.3 image is also available now.

3) Default emulator with Intel HAXM driver and Intel Atom android image. This option works for me with Android 4.2, but not with 2.3, so I can't really recommend it. But on a fast PC this is a viable option, given you have Intel CPU.

I am currently researching the options in detail. If you want to know more, I already [posted about Bluestacks](http://android.kul.is/).

Answer (score 2):

Check solution from http://www.manymo.com/. It might help you.

Comment: Sorry i want use the offline based ...

Answer (score 0):

check I found the solution

http://www.bobbychanblog.com/2011/07/faster-android-emulator-alternative-using-virtualbox/

using virtual os as an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 good alternatives:
1. AndroVM is a project based on Virtualbox. It's really fast but a bit complex to configure. 
2. Youwave is fast and simple. The only issue with it is, that it doesn't support native ARM code.

Answer (score -2):

Checkout GenyMotion
It is VirtualBox based. It is easy to configure(I did almost nothing). Extremely fast to start, run and deploy your app. It allows using your Webcam as the app's cam, etc.

If you try GenyMotion, don't forget to come back and upvote this answer